# How to produce a percent stacked bar chart; error occuring

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to create a percent stacked bar chart using this code. A data frame has already been created to have rows with only the conditions (stated in the code)

```
stacked_prep<- c(rep("Sharks, rays, and chimaeras" , 5) , rep("Marine mammals" , 5) , rep("Seabirds" , 5) , rep("Shorebirds" , 5))
condition <- rep(c("At risk fo becoming threatened" , "Data deficient" , "Not threatened", "Threatened") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(15 , 20 , 12))
data <- data.frame(stacked_prep,condition,value)
```

have also tried

```
condition <- rep(c("At risk fo becoming threatened" , "Data deficient" , "Not threatened", "Threatened") , 5); value <- abs(rnorm(20 , 20 , 12))
```

error produced:
arguments imply differing number of rows: 20, 15

However, this is the error that keeps on occurring, I have tried changing the "value" numbers

Error in data.frame(stacked_prep, condition, value) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 20, 16, 15

Any help would be great

Comment: As the error message is telling you: Your three vectors are of different lenghts. Maybe you want `condition <- rep(c("At risk fo becoming threatened" , "Data deficient" , "Not threatened", "Threatened") , 5); value <- abs(rnorm(20 , 20 , 12))`

Comment: I tried that and this errorr occured; error produced: arguments imply differing number of rows: 20, 15

Comment: The code provided in stefan's comment works fine. Please make sure to execute it in a fresh and clean R session! Afterwards, you might bind those vectors to a data frame by typing `df1 <- data.frame(condition, value)`.

Answer (score 1):

The length of each vector is different so you see this error. You can use this codes to make data frame

```
stacked_prep<- c(rep("Sharks, rays, and chimaeras" , 5) , rep("Marine mammals" , 5) , rep("Seabirds" , 5) , rep("Shorebirds" , 5))
condition <- rep(c("At risk fo becoming threatened" , "Data deficient" , "Not threatened", "Threatened") , 5)
value <- abs(rnorm(20 , 20 , 12))
data <- data.frame(stacked_prep,condition,value)
```

Comment: @rhelp if an answer solved your question don't forget to mark it as such with the green approval mark!